# access query switch has no syntax error but not the column showing anything?

Tags: vba, ms-access

thanks to SO I got to know about switch function yesterday.

I was wondering why my quantity is not showing up.. the whole column is blank..

I have looked up a lot about its sytax due to my error but none seems to be adaptable. 
I keep editing by line by line but can't solve it.

Apologies for the long table name

```
 Switch(dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType="B" 
And dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.OrderDate=dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.PromiseDate,
dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityOrderedOriginal-dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityBackordered,

dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType="B" 
And dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader.OrderDate<dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.PromiseDate,
dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityBackordered,

dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType="S",dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail.QuantityOrderedOriginal) AS qty
```

And the following is my thought process

- If OrderType is B  OrderType field

  And orderdate = promisedate
        Use quantity ordered – backordered
- If ordertype is B
        And orderdate =! promisedate 
          Use backordered qty
- If OrderType s,

  Use quantity ordered

Also, why is there a 'Enter Parameter Value' pop up for dbo_SO_$^@@#$.OrderType?

Thank you so much! I will be responsive as much as I can

Comment: A table alias might be in order.  ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain me about table alias?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM SuperlongTableNameIDontWantToType S`.  The `S` is the alias - you can refer to `SuperlongTableNameIDontWantToType.Foo` as `S.Foo` after that.

Comment: @Comintern thank you for comment! I was thinking for 30 mins but don't seem to understand.. so  should it be like Switch(dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType="s".dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType    ???

Comment: @Comintern and does my SQL look right? :) Thank you again!

Comment: @Comintern PLEASE disregard about my alias question. I mis-typed the table name..

Comment: I believe what @Comintern was saying is you can refer to tables with long names as an alias to avoid mistakes. an example would be:

`SELECT s.OrderType FROM dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader as s`

Comment: i'd also look at the `dbo_SO_SalesOrderHeader.OrderType` check of B or S, then your promise date check. Something like `select iif(X.OrderType="B",iif(Y.OrderDate=Z.PromiseDate,Z.QuantityOrderedOriginal-Z.QuantityBackOrdered,Z.QuantityBackOrdered),Z.QuantityOrderedOriginal) from dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader as X innerjoin dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader as Y innerjoin dbo_SO_SalesOrderHistoryDetail as z`  <-- not an answer!! Re aliasing, you've used an alias, `as Qty`, similar to that, `select t1.date from table1 as t1`